# Access Nginx by 127.0.0.1 works fine, but access by IP return 400

Tags: linux, networking, nginx, iptables

I deploy Django+uwsgi+Nginx project, but access nginx by 127.0.0.1 works fine, 400 returned if access by IP

The iptables shows

```sh
# iptables -L |grep 8181
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8181
```

And Nginx configure is

```sh
server {
    listen       8181 default;
    server_name  _;
```

The access log shows

```sh
192.168.1.131 - - [06/Dec/2013:09:55:16 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2013:10:08:08 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
```

What reason may cause this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the nginx access logs for the errors? They are normally at /var/log/nginx-error.log

Comment: @RamiroBerrelleza  I update access log

Comment: I just noticed that you're using Django. Have you checked that the 400 is not coming from Django or your application? 400 means bad request, which is typically an app-level error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [nginx documentation on server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) you are not supposed to use '_'. Instead, the recommendation is to use the default_server directive:

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    ...
}
```